# Sharepoint list webpart with links, how to add separator or header?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to understand how to add a separator or header in list webpart from sharepoint (I think running 2013 version)

I got this :

[image: From this]

And I want a "separator " like communities or other links :

[image: Want this]

I haven't access to sharepoint designer :(

It's a list webpart, but if I need to go on content editor to add some HTML code why not.

I have tried to use the 'group' function but it's really ugly

Answer (score 0):

You could custom SharePoint list view by CSR.

[Check here for CSR guideline](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

[One thread for your reference.](https://yassersherif.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/applying-sharepoint-2013-jslink-on-listviewwebpart-to-group-items-by-today-yesterday-last-week-same-as-microsoft-outlook-view/)